# How To Exit Infinite Loop Without Pausing Java

Tags: java

I have a Java program that automates a long list of tasks and it pauses for 15 seconds after each completed task then restarts. Is there a way to end this program by entering any keystrokes from the user? I don't want to have to ask the user if they want to end the program and have to stop and ask every so often as the user is not going to be around to respond. I know you can press "Control + C" to stop the program while in the command prompt but is there a more elegant way than this?
The program is something like this:

```
while(true) {
// automatic task code
}
```

Thank You

**Edit* My question is more of a "Can I make a program when I input an unsolicited input that can abruptly end the program?"

Comment: you can use `break`

Comment: So you necessarily want a break condition of a keyboard stroke?

Comment: This question is unclear.  Are asking how to break out of a loop, or how to get the the user to tell you went to break out os a loop?  What sort of program is this?  A console app with no GUI?  A console app with a GUI?  A Webapp?  A JavaFX app?  and Android app?  a Java ME app?  Something else?

Comment: Sorry. It's just a simple program. Nothing fancy. Pure text and no GUI. I want to exit out of the program during a random unsolicited time.

Comment: *"My question is more of a "Can I make a program when I input an unsolicited input that can abruptly end the program?"* - How about tell the about you tell us what your Question is ... not what it is like :-).   Because the answer to *that* question is "Yes you can".

Comment: *"I want to exit out of the program during a **random unsolicited time**."* - Man ... that is a complete contradiction of what you asked in the question.

Comment: Assume that you can, try something, and ask about that if you get stuck. Please see: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274)

Comment: It is better to search google and avoid asking question like that here.

Answer (score 0):

A simple break would do. Calling break exits the loop.

```
while(true) {

  if(conditionMet){ 
      break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break any loop using `break;`.
If your program is already listening for keyboard input, you just need to put that break command inside a conditional statement that checks for the desired input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.exit() OR break
The java.lang.System.exit() method terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine.

For example,

`// A Java program to demonstrate working of exit()`

`import java.util.*;`

`import java.lang.*;`

`class Test`

`{`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] >= 5)
        {
            System.out.println("exit...");

            // Terminate JVM
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("arr["+i+"] = " +
                              arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("End of Program");
}
```

`}`

This stops execution when it excounters System.exit().

When you use break statement,the control doesn't terminate the program,it comes out of the loop

`while(true){
//Critical task
break;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Below work around may help, especially for "for(;;)" infinite loop.

```
        // instance variable
        StudentRegistration stRegistration = new StudentRegistration();
        // to get user inputs
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        try {
            for(;;) {               
            System.out.println("\nEnter Student ID :");
            stRegistration.toSetStudentID(sc.nextInt());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            
        }
```