# How to stop while loop without break and exit in java

Tags: java

Suppose while loop is running infinitely how can we stop the loop without using break or System.exit(). And also we cannot add extra condition in the loop whatever we do should be outside the loop.
Can we achieve that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a code or is it just a theoretical question?

Comment: what about extract for loop in another method and using return inside loop?

Comment: Can this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827319/how-to-exit-infinite-loop-without-pausing-java/43827347 ?

Comment: this question was asked in interview

Comment: in this link they are using break but i am not allowed to use break in loop

Comment: If the loop is running inside a thread, the thread could be killed.

Comment: You could throw an exception.  Seems like a strange interview question though.  If anyone is writing production code that breaks out of infinite loops without using the language construct that was designed to do that, I'd be worried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not consider it good code, but for the sake of it (and because most interview questions have weird answers anyway), you could wrap the whole loop in a `try-catch` and throw an `Exception` inside the loop.

Or skip the catch block and throw a `RuntimeException` if the program execution does not need to continue.

Comment: You can also do another workaround by putting the loop in a method and exit the loop by returning from the method. Technically no `break` or `System.exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

they are some ways:

1- using return;

2- throw an exception and catch it next

3- I guess you have some loops or switches that you don't want to use break but you can name the loops and breaks to inner and outer break

Answer (score 0):

You can put your loop in a class method, and if you create a class instance and call the method to start the loop, you can stop the loop by destroying the process using another class method or by destroying the class instance. You can also call a function that does the output work from outside the loop.